# MFC CListCtrl - how to move item text to the left

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, win32gui, clistctrl

I'm trying to implement single-column `CListCtrl` (or `CMFCListCtrl`, doesn't matter) in a way, that some rows might have checkboxes and some might not (I don't want to use neither CListBox, nor CCheckListBox, because in the future I'm planning to use multiple columns). I'm using `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` style, but that forces every item to have a checkbox. Then I manually delete the checkbox with a custom draw handler, but then I'm having trouble moving the item's text to the left side so that it takes place of the erased checkbox.

This is what my list control looks like:

[image]

But I need it to look like this (item2 is aligned to the left border, taking place of the erased checkbox):

[image]

I create my list control dynamically like this:

```
    list->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | LVS_REPORT | LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER
                                            rect, this, SOME_ID);
    list->SetExtendedStyle(list->GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES);
```

And my custom draw handler function looks like this:

I create my list control dynamically like this:

```
void MyCListCtrl::OnCustomDraw(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lpn = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)pNMHDR;

    if (CDDS_PREPAINT == lpn->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        *pResult = CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW; // get notification for every row (item)
    }
    else if (CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT == lpn->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
        int row = lpn->nmcd.dwItemSpec;
        if (row == 1) { // we are in the first row (item2)
            lpn->nmcd.rc.left -= 20; // doesn't do anything
            lpn->rcText.left -= 20; // doesn't do anything

            // this erases checkbox from the current row
            SetItemState(row, INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(0), LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired result? Am I doing it the right way, or is it better to use CListCtrl without the `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` and draw the checkboxes myself where I want to? If so, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A list-view doesn't contain checkboxes. It simulates them using images instead. The `SetItemState` call doesn't *"erase \[the\] checkbox"*, but rather applies the image at index 0 in the image list. That's a fully transparent image with the same size as the checkbox images.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Is there any image in this image list, which has size "0", so that the text moves to the left instantly? Or can I create my own `CImageList` with the "checkbox" image and "empty" image with size 0 and if so, where can I find those images? Would this work? I'm quite new to the MFC programming, sorry for such questions.

Comment: A ListView does not support what you are looking for, when using its *standard* checkbox/image functionality. So disable that, and then draw your own checkboxes manually where needed. That means you will also have to handle mouse events to "toggle" your drawing

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. Can I somehow use the same images, that the CListCtrl uses? I can't have any resources (like images etc.) stored in my library.

Comment: You can use [DrawFrameControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawframecontrol) or [DrawThemeBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemebackground) (if you want to match the newer visual styles) to draw your control bitmaps.

Comment: If you want the entries like `item2` to be groups of sub-items there is a better approach: `CListCtrl::InsertGroup` . I am using it in a `CMFCListCtrl` and it works great. In the `LVITEM`of every descendant you will `InsertItem` , you need to append `| LVIF_GROUPID` to its `mask` and indicate the index of the group it belongs to in its `iGroupId`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try indentation with minus value (I didn't tried though):

```
LV_ITEM lvItem;
lvItem.iItem = nYourItem;
lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
lvItem.mask = LVIF_INDENT;
lvItem.iIndent = -1;

VERIFY(SetItem(&lvItem));
```

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that. It didn't work even if I set some custom image list (iIndent multiplied by image width represents the real indentation, but it only worked by moving the text to the right side, not left). Looks like the only option is to draw the bitmap manually, just like @IInspectable suggested. For now, I'm using CListCtrl simply with or without LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES.

Answer (score -2):

If it would be an option for you, why don't you just leave it as it is? 
The first version looks much more uncluttered, anyway.
The second version breaks guidance of the eyes.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please take the [tour].